# solr replication directory name not used

Tags: solr

When creating a backup, this code can be used:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/hellosolr/replication?command=backup&name=backup
```

It creates a folder in the data directory with naming convention `snapshot.timestamp`. However, according to https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/index-replication.html, the naming convention should be `snapshot.name` if `name` parameter is passed in the curl. Why is `name` ignored and timestamp is used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the parameter `name` - `&` means "run this command in the background" in regular shell.

Either escape it using `\&` or encapsulate your URL inside quotes:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/hellosolr/replication?command=backup&name=backup"
```

If you look at the output from your `curl` call you would see a `name: command not found` or something similar when not escaping the `&` properly.